# Java Floating License Server API?

Tags: java, api, licensing

Short of rolling your own.  There has to be something out there.  FlexLM/FlexNet is overpriced, and does not work for a company like ours.  The same goes for RLM.  There was one product I had hope in called LUM, but IBM no longer licenses the API.  So what else is available?  Or do you have any known way to get LUM?

Please help, I have been reviewing and searching on and off for over a year, and just can't find the right solution.  Maybe everyone just creates their own, we'd rather not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [Reprise](http://www.reprisesoftware.com/), coded by the people who originally wrote FlexLM. It's touted as cheaper and better than the original.

I haven't tried it yet, since I'm doing the same search as the OP.

Comment: I ended up using Reprise.  RLM is a great product and the support has been top Notch!

Answer (score 3):

Here's one product -- SoftwarePassport: http://www.siliconrealms.com/
They purchased Armadillo, which used to be an inexpensive software protection and licensing scheme.  The price is higher than it was back then but I'll bet it's still less than FlexLM.

I do have one suggestion regarding licensing -- as a user and developer of licensed software.  Implement a "soft cutoff", so that your customers are not dead in the water if the licensing mechanism fails (or if the license expires).  Provide some way for them to keep running so that there's enough time to remedy the problem.

Comment: I think I will have to download that and give it a spin.  Sounds like from their forum Java will have to use JNI calls to validate the license, it worries me that they use environment variables...  As for "soft cutoff" we have node locked license files, so our plan is to give them that if needed.

Comment: I think I should have used the term "soft fail".  I'm not sure exactly what you have in mind with using a node-locked license to solve the problem, but I assume that my suggestion is clear: that a customer never be left hanging because the licensing mechanism failed.

Comment: From their website: Starting on January 1, 2013, Software Passport terminated all sales for the Software Passport product lineup. Beginning on July 1, 2014, we will be removing the Software Passport website. In the near future, Software Passport will not be supported.